# Migrate users from 389 LDAP to Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, import, ldif

I want to migrate the users from 389 LDAP server to Azure Active Directory (Azure AD).
I tried following options -
1.I exported users from 389 into LDIF file using Apache Directory Studio client. But on Azure AD, there is no option to import users from LDIF file.
2.There is option in Azure AD for Bulk User Creation using CSV. So I exported users from 389 into CSV file using Apache Directory Studio client. But the CSV FORMAT expected by Azure AD for importing users is totally different from the one I get using Apache DS client.

Azure documentation also suggests to use LDIFDE utility.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555636

But I am not sure where to run LDIFDE utility? Do I need to use Cloud shell(Power shell/Bash?)
Does anybody have idea how to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Writing a script to convert the csv format would be what I would do :)